# algorithms used for content based image retrieval systems

Tags: java, image, image-processing, rgb, pixel

i recently heard about the topic called "content based image retrieval systems". i am trying to learn about the algorithms used in this topic.
I already found 2 algorithms.
1) AverageRGB- which calculates the average values of red,green and blue channel of each pixel in an image.

2) GlobalColorHistograms - which create a 64 buckets of colors using the 2 significant bits of RGB colorspace.

Here is my question.How is it that we are getting 64 distinct colors by taking 2 significant bits of RGB channels.What will be the value of the significant bits? i have looked at different places but couldn't understand anything.

Comment: Please include your sources so we all are in common agreement of what you are talking about. Since you have looked at different places, it should be easy to update the question with this information.

Comment: @mmgp : http://scien.stanford.edu/pages/labsite/2002/psych221/projects/02/sojeong/

Comment: I searched for `64` in that page and only thing I found was that the inputs were reduced to dimensions of `64 x 64`. I'm not asking you to help me in understanding what is CBIR, I'm asking you to improve your question.

Comment: The link is not working anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by splitting the RGB channels in `R`, `G`, and `B`. Given that you will pick only 2 bits, the only possible values are `00`, `01`, `10`, or `11`. No matter the values you have in each channel, these are the only four values you can obtain in a given channel. Supposing you found all the four values in each channel, then there are 64 possible 6-bit colors that you can build from that.

```
R: 00 01 10 11
G: 00 01 10 11
B: 00 01 10 11
```

With `R` at `00` you get 16 colors: `000000`, `000001`, `000010`, `000011`, `000100`, ... Then more 16 starting with `01` and so on, basics of combinatory.